# Make tkinter Canvas Zone darker

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm looking for a way to create in canvas brighter and darker areas. I searched a bit on the web but I didn't find any solutions so I was wondering if it was possible or not.
In summary I would like to set an area darker or brighter than another and also all the elements contained in that area (even images if there are )

Comment: You can create a black image with transparency to cover the region you want, then adjust its transparency to simulate the brightness.  You can use `Pillow` package to create the image.

Comment: Make the image with Photoshop or something, then put it in with `PIL` as the background.